# Allowing S3 bucket to access itself

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I just want my S3 bucket to be able to access itself. For example in my `index.html` there is a reference to a `favicon`, which resides in my s3 (the same actually) bucket. When i call the `index.html`, i get 403 HTTP ACCESS DENIED error.

If i put block all access off and i add a policy it works, but i do not want the Bucket to be public.

How am i able to invoke my website with my AWS user for example without making the site public (that is with having all internet access blocked)?

Comment: #1 Does your app have a login page or is a kind of landing? There are some resources that should be public and others private.

Comment: @JRichardsz The websites in the bucket should be only be able to see by a few dedicated users, which i will create with IAM.

Comment: I'm assuming that the login is provided by aws. Did you read about "Controlling access to a bucket with user policies"? Basically you could establish a relationship between your s3 files and your iam users. Will this help you?

Comment: @JRichardsz i am facing the problem even with the root account user, so i thought that this is a problem of the configuration of the bucket.

Comment: Check this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/walkthrough1.html  Also the favicon of a web is the most easy requirement that should not consume your invaluable time. Consider changing the architecture of your solution.  Nor gmail being gmail, it has the private favicon:  https://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/icons/mail/rfr/unreadcountfavicon/3/0.png

Comment: The S3 bucket never "accesses itself". It is the user's web browser that makes requests to S3.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, but the S3 bucket does not have to be public for that, right?

Comment: @David When accessing an S3 object via a URL, the object must either be public (via a bucket policy or an ACL), or the URL must include a **signature** that authorizes access to the object, such as using an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which is a time-limited URL that provides temporary access to a private object.

Answer (score 2):

> I just want my S3 bucket to be able to access itself.

no, the request always comes from the client

> How am i able to invoke my website with my AWS user

For the site-level access control there is CloudFront with [signed cookie](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html). You will still need some logic (apigw+lambda? lambda on edge? other server?) to authenticate the user and sign the cookie.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Without knowing how your bucket is set up and what permissions / access controls you have already deployed it is hard to give a definite answer.</strike>

Having said that it sounds like you simply need to walk through the proper steps for building an appropriate permission model. You have already explored part of this with the block all access and a policy, but there are also ACL's and permission specifics based on object ownership that need to be considered.

Ultimately AWS's documentation is going to do a better job than most to illustrate what to do and where to start:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteAccessPermissionsReqd.html

NOTE: if you share more information about how the bucket is configured and how your client side is accessing the website, I can edit the answer to give a more prescriptive solution (assuming the AWS docs don't get you all the way there)

**UPDATE**: After re-reading your question and comment on my answer, I think gusto2 and John's answers are pointing you in the right direction. What you are wanting to do is to authenticate users before they access the contents of the S3 bucket (which if I understand you right, is a s3 hosted static website). This means you need an authentication layer between the client and the bucket, which can be accomplished in a number of ways (lambda + cloudfront, or using an IdP like Cognito are certainly viable options). It would be a moot point for me to regurgitate exactly how to pull off something like this when there are a ton of accessible blog posts on the topic (search "Authenticate s3 static website").

HOWEVER I also want to point out that what you are wanting to accomplish is not possible in the way you are hoping to accomplish it (using IAM permission modeling to authenticate users against an s3 hosted static website). You can either authenticate users to your s3 website OR you can use IAM + S3 Permissions and ACL to set up AWS User and Role specific access to the contents of a bucket, but you can't use IAM users / roles as a method for authenticating client access to an S3 static website (not in any way I would imagine is simple or recommended at least...)

Comment: i just need a bucket, which certain users can invoke. The bucket contains multilple HTML sides which refer to some objects in the bucket. The bucket should not be public. That is basically all.

Answer (score 1):

You mention that "the websites in the bucket should be only be able to see by a few dedicated users, which i will create with IAM."

However, accessing Amazon S3 content with IAM credentials is not compatible with accessing objects via URLs in a web browser. IAM credentials can be used when making AWS API calls, but a different authentication method is required when accessing content via URLs. Authentication normally requires a back-end to perform the authentication steps, or you could use Amazon Cognito.